# Sockets programming: DIG DNS Query Messages: Incorrect header length?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, rfc, dig

## RFC Reference

I am working on a project which involves sockets programming and interpreting the output from DIG DNS queries.

I'm using RFC 1035 as my reference. Although this is quite old now (1987) as far as I can tell from later RFCs (for example 8490) the DNS headers are still the same.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035

## Code Overview: IPv6 TCP query

I have written a short program in C which reads from a IPv6 TCP socket. I send data to this socket using DIG. (My program simply reads all data it sees on a socket, and prints it to `stdout`.)

Note that there are two unusual things here:

- Firstly the use of IPv6
- Secondly the use of TCP (DNS messages are often UDP)

Here is the command used:

```
dig @::1 -p 8053 duckduckgo.com +tcp
```

I am running dig version `DiG 9.16.13-Debian`, on Debian Testing. (cera 2021-May)

## Output, Discussion and Question

Here is the hexadecimal and printable character output which is read from the socket:

```
Hex:
00 37 61 78 01 20 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 0A 64 75 63 6B 64 75 63 6B 67 6F 03 63 6F 6D 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 29 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 0A 00 08 00 7A 4* 48 2C 16 0* 33 
Char:
00  7 61  x 01 20 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 0A  d  u  c  k  d  u  c  k  g  o 03  c  o  m 00 00 01 00 01 00 00  ) 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 0A 00 08 00  z 4*  H  , 16 0* 33
```

If non-printable characters are encountered, the hex value is printed instead.

Although this is a fairly long stream of data, the question relates to the length of the header.

---

According to RFC 1035, the length of the header should be 12 bytes.

```
4.1.1. Header section format

The header contains the following fields:

                                    1  1  1  1  1  1
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                      ID                       |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    QDCOUNT                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    ANCOUNT                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    NSCOUNT                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    ARCOUNT                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

The header is followed by a `QUESTION SECTION`. The question section begins with a single byte which specifies the length.

---

Inspecting the data stream above, we see that the byte at offset 12 has a value of 0. I repeat it below with offset numbers to make it clear. The data is in the *middle row*, the row above and below are *byte offsets*.

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 <- byte 12
00 37 61 78 01 20 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 0A 64 75 63 6B ...
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 <- byte 15
```

This clearly doesn't make any sense.

Looking again at the stream, we can see that "duckduckgo" is preceeded by the byte `0A`. This is 10 in decimal and corresponds to the 10 characters of "duckduckgo". This string is followed by a byte `03` which corresponds to the 3 bytes of "com".

The offset of the byte `0A` is 15. *Not 12*.

I must have misunderstood the RFC specification. But what have I misunderstood? Does the header itself start at a different offset to what I think it is? (Byte zero.) Or is there perhaps some padding between the end of the header and the beginning of the first question section?

## Existing Question on this site:

Comments: The below link states that *there is no padding*. This is the only answer on this question. The question is about *DNS responses rather than queries*, and does not ask about the header section of a query. (Although information from one should presumably apply to the other, but possibly does not.)

[Do DNS messages pad names to an even number of bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858512/do-dns-messages-pad-names-to-an-even-number-of-bytes)

Comments: The below link asks about the best way to build a data structure to handle DNS data. Additionally, the answer notes that one has to be careful about network byte order and machine byte order. I am already aware of this and I use `ntohs()` to convert from network byte order to `x86_64` byte order before printing information to `stdout`. This is not the problem and does not explain why I see information about the dns query starting at byte 15 instead of 12, when the header should be a fixed size of 12 bytes.

[Implementing a DNS Query in c++ according to RFC 1035](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717644/implementing-a-dns-query-in-c-according-to-rfc-1035)

Comment: Could it be that your are missing that with TCP the message gets preceded by 2 bytes length information (see RFC 1035 4.2.2)? This is needed since TCP is a byte stream protocol and has no "message" semantic while UDP is a datagram protocol which has a clear message semantic already.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried something like that, but it didn't seem to make the data produced in the header "sensible". (The values still were not what I expected.) In addition, this accounts for 2 bytes. You might be correct about this, I will check again. But then what about the final missing byte? (Offset 12 -> 15?)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I re-enabled my `unsigned short` field at the start of my struct for the header. It now appears to be working without issue. I have no idea why this didn't work before, as this was my initial attempt at the implementation. I guess I must have missed something else which I've now accounted for. (Maybe I forgot about `ntohs()` before or something.) If you want to add a link to RFC 1035 4.2.2 as an answer I will accept it, and then add my struct definition.

Comment: I just had an idea, you did the work. Feel free to add the full answer yourself so that it helps others stumbling with similar issues.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ok I'll add a short summary

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SteffenUllrich who prompted the solution for this in the comments.

RFC 1035 4.2.2 states

```
4.2.2. TCP usage

Messages sent over TCP connections use server port 53 (decimal).  The
message is prefixed with a two byte length field which gives the message



Mockapetris                                                    [Page 32]
 
RFC 1035        Domain Implementation and Specification    November 1987


length, excluding the two byte length field.  This length field allows
the low-level processing to assemble a complete message before beginning
to parse it.
```

I had removed the 2-byte field at the start of my struct at some point.

This is what the structure looks like with the 2 byte length field re-enabled.

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) dns_header
{

    unsigned short ID;
    union
    {
        unsigned short FLAGS;

        struct
        {
            unsigned short QR : 1;
            unsigned short OPCODE : 4;
            unsigned short AA : 1;
            unsigned short TC : 1;
            unsigned short RD : 1;
            unsigned short RA : 1;
            unsigned short Z : 3;
            unsigned short RCODE : 4;
        };
    };
    unsigned short QDCOUNT;
    unsigned short ANCOUNT;
    unsigned short NSCOUNT;
    unsigned short ARCOUNT;

};


struct __attribute__((__packed__)) dns_struct_tcp
{

    unsigned short length; // length excluding 2 bytes for length field

    struct dns_header header;

};
```

For example: I recieved a TCP packet of length 53 bytes. The value of length is set to 51.

To read data into this struct:

```
memcpy(&dnsdata, buf, sizeof(struct dns_struct_tcp));
```

To interpret this data (since it is stored in network byte order):

```
void dns_header_print(FILE *file, const struct dns_header *header)
{

    fprintf(file, "ID: %u\n", ntohs(header->ID));
    char str_FLAGS[8 * sizeof(unsigned short) + 1];
    str_FLAGS[8 * sizeof(unsigned short)] = '\0';
    print_binary_16_fixed_width(str_FLAGS, header->FLAGS);
    fprintf(file, "FLAGS: %s\n", str_FLAGS);
    fprintf(file, "FLAGS: QOP  ATRRZZZR   \n");
    fprintf(file, "       RCODEACDA   CODE\n");
    fprintf(file, "QDCOUNT: %u\n", ntohs(header->QDCOUNT));
    fprintf(file, "ANCOUNT: %u\n", ntohs(header->ANCOUNT));
    fprintf(file, "NSCOUNT: %u\n", ntohs(header->NSCOUNT));
    fprintf(file, "ARCOUNT: %u\n", ntohs(header->ARCOUNT));
    
}
```

Note that the flags are unchanged, since each field of flags is less than 8 bits in length. However on `x86_64` systems, `unsigned short` is stored in little-endian format, hence `ntohs()` is use to convert data which is in big-endian (network) byte order to little-endian (host) byte order.